# Render partial error: undefined method `keys' for Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am allowing the `dispenser` to approve the `dispenser_review` using a remote link in rails. The approval in the DB is working, but the updating of the link on the page is not.

```
Rendered dispenser_reviews/update_approved_review.js.erb (1.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 22.4ms

NoMethodError - undefined method `keys' for #<Array:0x0000000e632500>:
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:330:in `find_partial'
```

**dispensers/show.html.erb**

```
<% @dispenser_reviews.all.each do |review| %>
  <p id="approval<%= review.id %>"><%= render :partial => 'approve_review', locals: { review: review } %></p>
<% end %>
```

**dispensers/_approve_review**

```
<% if review.approved %>
  <i class="icon-check-sign"></i>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Approve", approve_dispenser_review_path(review), :remote=>true %> <%= link_to "Approve with response", "#" %>
<% end %>
```

**dispenser_reviews_controller.rb**

```
def approve_dispenser_review
  @review = DispenserReview.find(params[:id])
  @review.approved = true
  @review.save
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :action => "update_approved_review", :layout => false }
  end
end
```

**dispenser_reviews/update_approved_review.js.erb**

```
$("#approval<%= @review.id %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'dispensers/approve_review', locals: [review: @review] )) %>")
```

Comment: I assume on every update, the first link on the list gets updated.  If this is the problem in question then you need to ensure that `<p id="approve">` is modified to have unique value for each `review` in that loop.

Comment: Oh yeah. How could I miss that.

Comment: However, I still have this problem: render(:partial => 'dispensers/approve_review', locals: [review: @review] )
NoMethodError: undefined method `keys' for #<Array:0x0000000c19ee00>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update `dispenser_reviews/update_approved_review.js.erb` as

```
$("#approval<%= @review.id %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'dispensers/approve_review', locals: {review: @review} ))
```

`locals: {review: @review}` and not `locals:[review: @review]`.

Pass a Hash not an Array of Hash.

Comment: No worries. That happens with everyone. :)